# Using node-fetch effectively, getting invalid json response body error *only* the first time I query the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, fetch

I have been attempting to collect an API token from an undocumented API of a Ubiquiti EdgeMax Network switch and use it to check the status of the ports then eventually make some changes to the status of them when I receive the correct information.

I have put together some code using NodeJS and node-fetch that allows me to grab the API authentication token then use it to get some information on the interfaces.

It all seems to be working fine but I have noticed that the first time I run the NodeJS application and query it it would throw an

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at... reason: Unexpected end of JSON input`

This happens when I request the data to the switch with the API using the token. If I try the second time it works fine, even on multiple consecutive times.

I tried getting tweaking the async functions but the behavior is the same, is as if the token is not gathered quickly enough the first time the request is done. I am not as good with async JS code conventions so I wonder if is something wrong with my approach.

I just want to be able to make each of these request actions one after another effectively and return back the result to the server I'm making the query from. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const url = "https://example.com:9443/";
const credentials = { username: "ubnt", password: "ubnt" };
let status;
let token;

async function postData(url = '', path = '', body = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}${path}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      Referer: url,
      accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }).then(response => response.json().then(json => ({
    authToken: response.headers.get("x-auth-token"),
    json
  })))
  return response;
}

async function getData(url = '', path = '', token = '') {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}${path}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      Referer: url,
      accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "x-auth-token": token
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: null
  }).then(response => response.json())
  return response;
}

const statusHandler = (req, res) => {
  const {
    seed
  } = req.body.input;

  postData(url, 'api/v1.0/user/login', credentials)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.authToken);
      token = response.authToken;
    }).then(getData(url, 'api/v1.0/interfaces', token)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response[0].status);
        status = response[0].status;
      }));

  console.log(seed);

  return res.json({
    status,
  });
};

app.post("/status", statusHandler);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the functions incorrectly. I did not use an async function for the statusHandler. I was was not waiting for the reply from the api before proceeding with the next request. It seems that with the first requests the API responds a lot slower.

I fixed by waiting for a reply on each of the function declarations and their calls on the handler using async / await. Doing this allowed me to clean up the code a lot more making it more readable.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const url = "https://example.com:9443/";
const credentials = { username: "ubnt", password: "ubnt" };
let status;
let token;

async function postData(url = '', path = '', body = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}${path}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      Referer: url,
      accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })

  const json = await response.json()
    .then(json => ({
      authToken: response.headers.get("x-auth-token"),
      json
    }));
  return json
}

async function getData(url = '', path = '', token = '') {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}${path}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      Referer: url,
      accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "x-auth-token": token
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: null
  })
  const json = await response.json()
  return json
}

const statusHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    seed
  } = req.body.input;

  await postData(url, 'api/v1.0/user/login', credentials)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.authToken);
      token = response.authToken;
    })

  await getData(url, 'api/v1.0/interfaces', token)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response[0].status);
      status = response[0].status;
    });

  console.log(seed);

  return res.json({
    status,
  });
};

app.post("/status", statusHandler);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```